# Diode and resistance electronic

Tags: voltage, power, current, electrical

Can you tell me what is different between two circuit:

One AC source and resistance in series
[image: r load]

second AC source, diode and resistance in series either:

[image]

Can you show the difference in equations?

I need also p(t), .

Comment: Is the breakdown voltage of the diode higher or lower than voltage of the source?

Comment: The formatting and vagueness of this question, even with the diagrams, makes me feel that even if I served the question on a silver platter it would still not hit home. With that said I strongly recommend you to play around with a simulator that works awesome in the web browser (free). Here's the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html). Spend hours on it and then come back with a precise question if there's something you don't understand.

Comment: i just ask what is difference i mean what diode will change in the circuit ?

Comment: @LubnaMahmood if you open the link and make your circuit in there you'll notice that the diode will only let the current flow in one direction. So in your first diagram, imagine that one of the bumps disappear and just goes flat. I won't say which of the bumps because the diode's direction matters. But if it is as in the bottom circuit then the bump to the right will be flat.

Comment: that's mean nothing change in equations right ?

Comment: @LubnaMahmood or you can just do like Tony Stewart did, he clicked the link and then he pressed "Circuits" > "Diodes" > "Half-wave rectifier". And then he turned that into a link and pasted it in his answer. He's awesome.

Comment: Yes Falstad's simulator is awesome. Each diode has a property of Vf at some current (right mouse) But Voltage sources and Op Amps are ideal with some GBW option only but 0 Zout. So one must learn the non ideal values and add them.

Answer (score 0):

The diode acts like a switch with a low threshold voltage Vf like 0.7V for Silicon.

[There are reverse voltage limits on every diode and forward bulk resistance that may increase Vf with current.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2013.097415321081861%2055%205%2050%0Av%20112%20320%20112%2096%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20416%2096%20416%20320%200%20640%0Ad%20112%2096%20416%2096%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20112%20320%20416%20320%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%204099%205%200.0125%200%202%200%203%0Ao%201%2064%200%204099%205%200.0125%201%202%201%203%0A)  ( Falstad browser simulator link)

The equation changes since the conduction resistance changes with voltage polarity so you end up with a half sine wave. ( or lookup half-wave rectifier)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:: Cut off the negative half of the wave and takes 0.7v of the positive half